# when i use angular 2 and with formly Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?

Tags: html, angular, angular-formly

i use formly for generate form in angular 2 and i want to change form of input date to 'YYYY-MM-DD'.can i?

```
{
  className: 'col-4',
   type: 'input',
    key: 'registerDate',
     templateOptions: {
      type: 'date',
      label: 'Date 1',
    }   
},
```

Comment: Input type date take date format based on user browser. So No, you cannot change any behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a date change at back-end, you can make use of the Date library.

```
myObj.Date = new Date();
```

There are many Utility methods with it, which can be used.

If you want to display the date with a changed format on UI, you can display it as follows:

```
{{myObj.Date | date: 'medium'}}
```

similarly you can set Date formats, depending on you need. 
 To learn more on that read 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

The native input doesn't support passing a custom format so
instead you have to use a custom datepicker formly type.

Here is an example that use material datepicker: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkwj6z